# What is the normalized graph matrix if the row-sum of proximity matrix is zero?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, symmetric-matrices, graph-laplacian

Let $S \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^{n \times n}$ be the proximity (or similarity) matrix of a graph, e.g.
$$
S = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0.9 & 0.3 \\
0.9 & 0 & 0.4 \\
0.3 & 0.4 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
Here, the elements on the diag should be $0$s.

Now, we define $D$ be a diagonal matrix with the row-sum of $S$ on the diagonal entries. In my running example, 
$$
D = \left[ \begin{matrix}
1.2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1.3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.7
\end{matrix}\right]
$$

Then, we normalize $S$ with $D$, i.e.
$$
\begin{align}
\bar{S} &= D^{-\frac{1}{2}} S D^{-\frac{1}{2}} \\
&= \left[ \begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1.2}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1.3}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{0.7}}
\end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0.9 & 0.3 \\
0.9 & 0 & 0.4 \\
0.3 & 0.4 & 0
\end{matrix}\right] \left[ \begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1.2}} & 0 & 0 \\
0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{1.3}} & 0 \\
0 & 0 & \frac{1}{\sqrt{0.7}}
\end{matrix}\right] \\
\end{align} 
$$
(omit subsequent steps...)

**My question is: How can I handle when the row-sum of $S$ is zero?**

Specifically, if 
$$
S = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0 & 0 & 0.3 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0.3 & 0 & 0
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
i.e. no edge is connected to vertex 2. Thus, $D$ will be
$$
D = \left[ \begin{matrix}
0.3 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0.3
\end{matrix}\right]
$$
As a result, I don't know how to compute $D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$.  So, what is the correct calculation method for $D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ and $\bar{S}$ hereafter at this time?

Comment: Not my field, but are you referring to the [Graph Distance Matrix](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphDistanceMatrix.html)? Would a zero column indicate that a given vertex was distance zero from every other vertex? Is that permitted in such a matrix?

Comment: @TheoBendit Maybe Graph Distance Matrix is what I refer. I look up [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Random_walk_normalized_Laplacian_2) and find a sentence in the 2nd para., it says "For the isolated vertices (those with degree 0), a common choice is to set the corresponding element ${\textstyle L_{i,i}^{\text{rw}}}$ to 0." Is it right for my question?

Comment: It doesn't look right for your question. The Laplacian matrix has negative entries, whereas your matrices don't seem to. Could you define what a proximity matrix is? Am I correct in thinking that it's an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ defined by $n$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ where $A_{ij} = d(x_i, x_j)$?

Comment: @TheoBendit Yes, your understanding is right!

Comment: OK, so then the $i$th column totalling zero can only happen if every entry is $0$, since every distance is non-negative. This means that $d(x_i, x_j) = 0$ for all $j$, which presumably means that $x_i = x_j$ for all $j$. That is, every point is equal to every other point, and the whole matrix is the zero matrix. This seems like a pretty degenerate case, and I suspect that such a case is either purposefully excluded, or already normalised without having to conjugate by $D^{\frac{1}{2}}$.

Comment: @TheoBendit My graph is a Protein-Protein Interaction Network and just downloaded from the website. The entry $S_{i,j}$ denotes the confidence score (range 0 to 1) between protein $i$ and protein $j$, the higher the score is, the more confident these two proteins are closely related. The zero row-sum occurs due to the missing value problem, i.e. protein $i$ is not in the PPI network but I need the augmented matrix (add missing proteins) to do the subsequent process. So, don't bother with missing proteins?

Comment: I'd guess that, mathematically, the zero columns are pretty disastrous. Yes, I would ignore the missing proteins... I think. I don't know how important it is to include all proteins, or to track which proteins are missing, etc. To know that, I'd have to know all about your problem (which I don't want to do!), but I would say, for the purposes of the maths you're asking about here, ignore the missing proteins.

Comment: @TheoBendit OK, thank you for your comment! ^-^

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

(This is just an expansion on the points in the comments above, so that the question has a proper answer.)

Given $n$ points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ in a metric space $(X, d)$ (e.g. $X = \Bbb{R}^m$ with the Euclidean distance function), the proximity matrix $A$ is defined by $A_{ij} = d(x_i, x_j)$. Naturally, the symmetry of metrics imply that $A$ must be symmetric, and the positive-definiteness of the metric implies that the entries of $A$ are non-negative, with $0$s down the diagonal.

However, not every symmetric matrix with non-negative entries and $0$s down the diagonal will be a proximity matrix. Indeed, the example provided:
$$S = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0.3 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0.3 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
cannot be a proximity matrix, as we have
$$d(x_1, x_3) = 0.3 > 0 + 0 = d(x_1, x_2) + d(x_2, x_3),$$
violating triangle inequality.

Indeed, if the $j$th column of the matrix sums to $0$, then we have $d(x_i, x_j) = 0$ for all $i$, as each entry is non-negative. By the definiteness of the metric, this implies $x_i = x_j$ for all $i$. That is, all the points are the same! In such cases, every entry in the proximity matrix must be $0$.

Can this ever happen? Sure, if all the points are the same. If not, then all the column sums are strictly positive, and computation of $D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ is straight forward.

Is this allowed to happen? Maybe; it depends on the circumstances. Certainly such a case is pretty degenerate, and I could foresee many applications of proximity matrices rejecting such a case, or treating it specially.

Ultimately, it's up to the individual to decide what their proximity matrix is modelling, and what every point being identical says about the situation they're modelling.

In this case, you indicated that this was modelling protein interactions, with $0$ columns appearing when data was missing. It's difficult to tell without a much wider perspective, but it would appear that filling in missing data with zeros breaks the proximity matrix, for the reasons argued above (it makes the matrix not a valid proximity matrix). If you don't have data on a given protein, then try performing your analysis with one fewer protein.

Comment: Thank you for ur very long supplement! Grateful!